# Top 5 most common words in Python

Tags: python, strings

I would like to hear feedback from an interviewer's perspective on how to improve the following code:

```
from collections import Counter

def word_map(string):
    word_dict = {}
    stop_word_file=open("stopwords.txt", "r")
    stop_words =stop_word_file.read().split()
    for word in string.split():
        word = filter(str.isalnum, word).lower()
        word = word.strip()
        if word != '' and word not in stop_words:
            if word in word_dict.keys():
                word_dict[word] +=1
            else:
                word_dict[word] = 1

    return word_dict

file = open("story.txt", "r")

five_top_words = Counter(word_map(file.read())).most_common(5)
for letter, count in five_top_words:
    print '%s : %10d' %(letter, count)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `'stopwords.txt'` exactly, what would be a typical content?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger `wget https://www.lexalytics.com/files/stopwords.txt`

Comment: This answers the content part, but not really the purpose. Why would you want to filter out such words?

Comment: http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2014/pdf/292_Paper.pdf as an example in sentiment analysis or any other kind of tweet processing you might want to remove the stop words.

Comment: That's strange, the abstract of the paper you linked to state that "Our results show that using pre-compiled list of stopwords negatively impacts the performances". But I get the idea. Will keep on reading.

Comment: Yeah that is an interesting read however sometimes you might be asked to remove the stop words. "Words in a document that are frequently occurring but meaningless in terms of Information Retrieval (IR) are called stop words. It is repeatedly claimed that stopwords do not
contribute towards the context or information of the documents
and they should be removed during indexing as well
as before querying by an IR system. However, the use of
a single fixed stopword list across different document collections
could be detrimental to the retrieval effectiveness"

Comment: if interested have a look at here http://terrierteam.dcs.gla.ac.uk/publications/rtlo_DIRpaper.pdf you can use tf-idf for autogeneration of stopwords as well

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: in practice for this particular problem, it's because if you don't remove stopwords, then the top 5 words in almost any corpus will be 5 of "the", "be", "to", "of", "and", "a", "in", "that", "have", "I". Whereas on a good day, the top 5 non-stopwords in a corpus will have something to do with its subject matter!

Comment: With a bit of work your tokenizer could be broken by corner cases. "the interviewer's opinion" vs "the three interviewers" -- those are different words (interviewer's vs interviewers) but you are counting them the same.  The solutions would be to use a proper tokenizer like from [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). Would you like me to extend this into an answer?

Comment: Now I want to know which words appear most frequently in Python code.

Comment: yeah why not @Oxinabox always like to learn more!

Comment: The not is because it is work for me, which would be wasted if you wanted a stand-alone implementation, or didn't care about corner cases. Some more also "its" vs "it's", and "we'll" vs "well", and "I'll" vs "ill". Another possibility is the traditional tokenizing of things like "isn't" as "is", and "n't", which may or may not be desirable. I'll write an answer up later (poke me if I don't)

Answer (score 4):

I second [@Dannnno](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/129795/84718) arguments except for the fact that you don't need to split the work into tinier functions.

In fact I'd say quite the opposite as using more function let you turn them into generators for a more efficient memory usage.

You should also make yourself familiar with the `str.format` syntax which is the new way to go over the `%` formatting syntax.

My proposal is:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain


def word_map(filename, stop_words_file):
    with open(stop_words_file) as f:
        stop_words = set(f.read().split())

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            words = (filter(str.isalnum, w).lower() for w in line.split())
            yield (w for w in words if w and w not in stop_words)


def top_words(filename, stopfile, count):
    words = chain.from_iterable(word_map(filename, stopfile))
    return Counter(words).most_common(count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for word, count in top_words('story.txt', 'stopwords.txt', 5):
        print '{} : {:>10}'.format(word, count)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is make this a "proper" script - functions, and an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. This allows it to be executed as a standalone script, or imported as needed.

Next, you need to make sure to close your files. The easiest way to do this is with [context managers](http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/).

Next you'll want to make it a but more generalized - pass more things as parameters instead of hardcoding them. This includes filenames, the number of words, etc.

Next, store your `stop_words` in a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) for more efficient lookup.

Next, use the `Counter` more effectively by using it within the `word_map` function and using a list comprehension as well.  Write a function to filter for readability.

Lastly, use better names and combine your two helper functions - they're simple enough that you don't need both of them.

```
from collections import Counter

def find_n_top_words(source_filename, stopwords_filename, num_top_words):
    with open(source_filename, 'r') as source_file, \
         open(stopwords_filename, 'r') as stop_word_file:

        stop_words = frozenset(stop_word_file.read().split())
        words = [filter(word.isalnum).lower().strip() for word in string.split()]

        def filter_func(word):
            return word and word not in stopwords

        filtered_words = filter(filter_func, words)
        word_dict = Counter(filtered_Words)
        top_words = word_dict.most_common(num_top_words)
        for word, count in top_words:
            print '%s : %10d' % (word, count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_n_top_words('story.txt', 'stopwords.txt', 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest these changes:

1. Use a `frozenset` for the stop words.
2. Create a cached global variable for the stop words and filespec. Use the filespec to determine when to load/reload.
3. Accept an optional named parameter for the stopwords file. If no value is given, use a default value (or die).
4. Create the Counter in your function.
5. Either return the Counter, or return the Counter's `.most_common` words, as you like.